# Writing 2 algorithms using enumerate in a 2-column array for a presentation

Tags: beamer

Good day.
I intend to compare two algorithms using enumerate in beamer for a presentation. However, I intend for each successive row in each column to appear. For example, step1 to step 4 for column 1 and then step1 to step4 for column 2. Here is an illustration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{GA versus $\tau$-Leaping}{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1->}c >{\onslide<2->}c}
%    \hline
GA & $\tau$-Leaping  \\ % \hline
step 1 & step 1     \\
%    \hline
step 2 & step 2      \\ 
%    \hline
step 3 & step 3    \\
%    \hline
step 4 & step 4    \\
%    \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Each column looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\textcolor{cyan}{STEP \arabic*}}]
\item 
Develop the model according to the chemistry of reaction in Table 1

\item
By applying the stochastic constants, \(c_{\mu}\),compute the 
respective cummulative propensities for each of the chain reaction ,\(R_{\mu}\) by using the 
equation :
\begin{equation*}
\alpha_{\mu} = \sum_{\mu}^{}c_{\mu}h_{\mu}  
\end{equation*}
Where \(\mu =(1,2,3,\ldots ,N\)) and \(h_{\mu}\) is the number of instant combination of 
reactants for reaction, \(R_{\mu}\).
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use enumitem with beamer, they are  not compatible

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use columns to present content next to each other:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->][Step 1.]
\item 
Develop the model according to the chemistry of reaction in Table 1

\item
By applying the stochastic constants, \(c_{\mu}\),compute the 
respective cummulative propensities for each of the chain reaction ,\(R_{\mu}\) by using the 
equation :
\begin{equation*}
\alpha_{\mu} = \sum_{\mu}^{}c_{\mu}h_{\mu}  
\end{equation*}
Where \(\mu =(1,2,3,\ldots ,N\)) and \(h_{\mu}\) is the number of instant combination of 
reactants for reaction, \(R_{\mu}\).
\end{enumerate}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->][Step 1.]
\item 
Develop the model according to the chemistry of reaction in Table 1

\item
By applying the stochastic constants, \(c_{\mu}\),compute the 
respective cummulative propensities for each of the chain reaction ,\(R_{\mu}\) by using the 
equation :
\begin{equation*}
\alpha_{\mu} = \sum_{\mu}^{}c_{\mu}h_{\mu}  
\end{equation*}
Where \(\mu =(1,2,3,\ldots ,N\)) and \(h_{\mu}\) is the number of instant combination of 
reactants for reaction, \(R_{\mu}\).
\end{enumerate}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz. It worked.

Comment: @teddiclax You're welcome!

Comment: Hello @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz. Now I have got a problem. The texts in the steps tends to cut off at the end of the slide. How to do I continue,writing the algorithm into another slide without restarting the count. The algorithm has 4 steps.Thanks.

Comment: @teddiclax if you have a new problem, please ask a new question

Comment: No. @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz. I don't have a new question. still referring to the above solution.

Comment: @teddiclax Good luck then!